# Make a Simple Pie Graph using Bash Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, solaris, sunos

Below is my Bash Shell Script from which I am executing my two Hive SQL Queries which is working fine. And I am calculating `Error Percentage` in this Bash Shell Script.

```
#!/bin/bash

QUERY1=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT SUM(total_items_purchased), SUM(total_items_missingormismatch) from lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';"`

QUERY2=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT 100 * SUM(total_items_missingormismatch*1.0) / SUM(total_items_purchased) FROM lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';"`


mailx -s "LIP Data Quality Report for $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1" -r rj@host.com rj@host.com  <<EOF
Data Successfully loaded into LIP_DATA_QUALITY table

Total Items Purchased: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $1}'`

Total Items MissingorMismatch: `echo $QUERY1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Error Percentage: $QUERY2
EOF
```

**Problem Statement:-**

I will be getting `Error Percentage` number in `$QUERY2`. I need to make a Simple Pie Graph that can show `Error Percentage` and `No Error Percentage` by using the number from `$QUERY2` just like below graph using Bash Shell Script.

[image]

I am running `SunOS`. Is this possible to do in Bash Shell script? Any thoughts will be appreciated.

**Update:-**

Below is the Shell Script that I am using, that I created using `vi editor`.

```
 1  #! /bin/bash
 2
 3  TEMP=$(mktemp -t chart)
 4  QUERY1=36
 5  QUERY2=64
 6  cat > $TEMP <<EOF
 7      <html>
 8        <head>
 9          <!--Load the AJAX API-->
10          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
11          <script type="text/javascript">
12
13            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
14            google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
15
16            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
17            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
18
19            // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
20            // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
21            // draws it.
22            function drawChart() {
23
24              // Create the data table.
25              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
26              data.addColumn('string', 'Title');
27              data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
28              data.addRows([
29                ['Error Percentage', $QUERY1],
30                ['No Error Percentage', $QUERY2]
31              ]);
32
33              // Set chart options
34              var options = {'title':'Errors',
35                             'width':400,
36                             'height':300};
37
38              // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
39              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
40              chart.draw(data, options);
41            }
42          </script>
43        </head>
44
45        <body>
46          <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
47          <div id="chart_div"></div>
48        </body>
49      </html>
50      EOF
51
52      # open browser
53      case $(uname) in
54         Darwin)
55            open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app $TEMP
56            ;;
57
58         Linux|SunOS)
59            firefox $TEMP
60            ;;
61       esac
62
```

Error that I got after running the above shell script as `sh -x chart.sh`-

```
bash-3.00$ sh -x chart.sh
chart.sh: syntax error at line 3: `TEMP=$' unexpected
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

**Another Update:-**

After the below suggestions, when I tried something like this-I got another error.

```
bash-3.00$ bash -x chart.sh
++ mktemp -t chart
mktemp: failed to create file: /tmp/chart
+ TEMP=
+ QUERY1=36
+ QUERY2=64
+ cat
chart.sh: line 6: $TEMP: ambiguous redirect
```

Another Update: Made Some Progress I guess. Not sure where the output files will be going? Or it will open into a browser?

```
bash-3.00$ bash -x chart.sh
++ mktemp -t chart
+ TEMP=/tmp/chart
+ QUERY1=36
+ QUERY2=64
+ cat
++ uname
```

Comment: Look at [`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way of creating a [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/):

```
#! /bin/bash

TEMP=$(mktemp -t chart.XXXXX)
QUERY1=36
QUERY2=64
cat > $TEMP <<EOF
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Title');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
        data.addRows([
          ['Error Percentage', $QUERY1],
          ['No Error Percentage', $QUERY2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Errors',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
EOF

# open browser
case $(uname) in
   Darwin)
      open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app $TEMP
      ;;

   Linux|SunOS)
      firefox $TEMP
      ;;
 esac
```

if you save it as `chart.sh` then run it as

```
$ bash -x chart.sh
```

or

```
$ chmod +x chart.sh
$ ./chart.sh
```

which gives you something like

[image]

Notice that you only need `bash` and an Internet connection, there's nothing to install.

`mktemp` should be available in Solaris (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/mktemp-1.html). If you don't have it just set TEMP to whatever file you want the HTML output to be.

Comment: Thanks dtmilano, for the suggestion. I tried copy pasting the whole command in bash shell script. But I got some error. I have updated my question what shell script I am running, and what error I got. Any suggestion will be appreciated. And also do I need to install anything before running this shell script?

Comment: Thanks dtmilano for the edit. I made some progress with that, but I got another error- `bash-3.00$ bash -x chart.sh
++ mktemp -t chart
mktemp: failed to create file: /tmp/chart
+ TEMP=
+ cat
chart.sh: line 4: $TEMP: ambiguous redirect
+ open -a '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'
chart.sh: line 51: open: command not found
`. I have also updated in the question.

Comment: Thanks dtmilano for the edit again. I made some progress again. This time I didn't got any error. I just wanted to know, how I will be seeing the output? It will open the browser? or it will save the png file somewhere on my machine. Updated my question with the output I got after running the shell script. Or it will give me an HTML file, then I need to view the html file for the actual result to see?

Comment: What's the output printed by uname? The HTML content is in $TEMP.

Comment: This is what I got above if I type uname. I can see html content in tmp folder as a chart name. But how can I see the graph I need to open the html file to see the graph?

Comment: Yes, open it with a browser. The script should do it automatically if you can open firefox from command line.

Comment: how can I open that chart file name from the bash command prompt in firefox? Is there any command to open any file name in the fireforx? Or I need to scp from UNIX to WINDOWS then I can open that file in any browser?

Comment: firefox $TEMP should work. But you can also scp to Windows if you feel more confortable.

Comment: I don't normally waste downvotes, but this gets one - because you basically just completely ignored the OP, threw his attempt in the bin, and wrote him a new program.  That doesn't improve SO

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to create a pie chart in only shell, is to generate an svg image.

A simple/small program to generate other image types is Ploticus.
 http://ploticus.sourceforge.net/doc/welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no native way of doing it, so I would assume that your best bet is to get a third party tool installed, like-

[`PLOTRIX`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html)

[Documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/plotrix.pdf)